# ssh remote forward with two clients behind hop and a server on local network

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, remote, forwarding

I'm trying to connect two clients which are in different environnements to a single license server. 
I have a direct access from my computer to the license server but i have a hop to access clients. 
My question is simple, I would like to connect both clients to the server on the port 8080 form my computer.
I was thinking to do that but it's not working.(working only for the first)

```
autossh -M 0 -q -N -o "ServerAliveInterval=60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax=3" -L 10001:CLIENT1:22 -i /home/.../.../id_rsa user@HOP_ADDRESS -vvv &
autossh -M 0 -q -N -o "ServerAliveInterval=60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax=3" -i /home/.../.../key.pem -p 10001 user@localhost -R 8080:LICENSESERVERIP:8080 -vvv &
autossh -M 0 -q -N -o "ServerAliveInterval=60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax=3" -L 10002:CLIENT2:22 -i /home/.../.../id_rsa user@HOP_ADDRESS -vvv &
autossh -M 0 -q -N -o "ServerAliveInterval=60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax=3" -i /home/.../.../key.pem -p 10002 user@localhost -R 8080:LICENSESERVERIP:8080 -vvv &
```

[image: schema of the architecture]